# overflow-x html issue

Tags: html, css, iframe

Im having a small issue with an iframe I'm using on my website. For some reason I can't get the iframe to not show a horizontal scroll bar at the bottom.

Here's my code:

```
<center>
   <iframe height="1330" width="100%" src="http://SentinelGaming.spreadshirt.com/" name="Spreadshop" itemscope itemtype="http://www.sentinelgaming.net/store" id="spreadshop" frameborder="0" scrollbar="no" ></iframe>
</center>

<style>
#spreadshop {
overflow-x: hidden;
}
</style>
```

Heres the page you can look at to see what I'm talking about: http://www.sentinelgaming.net/store

Comment: Are you sure this is not a browser specific problem? I see no scrollbars on the site.

Comment: The site itself has a horizontal scrollbar but not the store iframe.

Comment: Probably not related but the center tag is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In short, it don't think it is possible to hide the overflow of an iframe. I believe the main reason is security. The idea is that you should not be able to hide parts of the loaded source from being shown.

I've made a [small example](http://jsfiddle.net/Dujzq/) showing how the overflow-property is being ignored.

```
<iframe src="http://cnn.com"></iframe">

iframe {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The above example will add both vertical- and horizontal scroll bars to the iframe, even though we explicitly tell it not to.

**Possible workaround:**

A possible workaround would be to load the content through AJAX, add the content to a div, and have an overflow-property set on that div.

*It would require that the user have JavaScript enabled, but I believe this is the closest you get to a solution.*